# GCP /dev/sdb1 /home is full but I have no projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCP and just experimenting. Tried to install something in one of my projects and got a disk full exception. Rather than buy more I thought I would just do some cleanup.

I have now deleted *ALL* instances, buckets and projects. I know projects take awhile to be deleted so maybe one of them is consuming a lot of disk. Question:

1. How can I remove/delete whatever is consuming 99% + of `/dev/sdb1 /home` ? or ...
2. Increase the size of that resource?

Comment: You're conflating several GCP concepts. buckets, projects, and other GCP resources are not related to GCE instances, and do not consume disk space. If you need more disk space, you can edit your instance to increase the size of the disk.

Comment: I don't think I'm conflating anything Travis. Please re-read my question. I can't increase disk on an instance that doesn't exist - and I have _no_instances; removed them all. I also deleted all projects.  I do have a couple buckets but I assume they are different animals altogether.

So, without any instances or projects this is what I get when I run `sudo df -h` from the terminal:
/dev/sdb1       4.8G  4.5G   81M  99% /home
/dev/sda1        41G   31G   11G  75% /root

Comment: What are you running `df -h` on? Your home computer or a GCE instance? You said that you have no instances. Google Cloud does not affect your home computer. There are many tools including `ls -l` and `find` to see what is on a file system. In your case try this `ls -lR /home`.

Comment: @GDB Are you on Cloud Shell? If yes, you have only 5Gb of disk and you can't increase it. It's only a workspace for temporary or light things, not for installing (heavy) software.

Comment: You are correct Guillaume. See my comment below the accepted answer. John: "running `df -h` on my home computer"? LOL. Um, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using Cloud Shell. The Cloud shell [comes with only 5GB](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#persistent_disk_storage) 
for storage, and no way to increase.

One possible solution would be to setup `gcloud SDK` on your own machine or GCE (Google Compute Engine) instance instead.

I hope this approach works for you.

Comment: Ahmed I think you nailed it. That's almost certainly what I've done. Pretty sure it was from installing Anaconda packages. Noob fail.

Comment: From 99% to  6%  in /home. Noob fail was installing Anaconda in the "default" directory and cloning a repo in there as well. Thanks Ahmed.

Comment: Ahmed, another question: `/root` is at 75% of capacity (31 out of 41G). That seems high. Have I somehow managed to screw it up or is that normal utilization? `ls` doesn't return anything.

Comment: No. you cannot make any change